# CSS: Is it possible to have a 3-column layout with BOTH the left column and center column flexibly filling the space?

Tags: css, position, positioning

It is possible to use `position:absolute` and `left` and `right` on the middle column to set where it ends in relation to the parent div.

However I'd like to be able to have the left side of the center div to start right where the left column ends, and for the left column to be adjustable (based on its content).

This seems like a really basic thing but from what I understand there is no way to do this without flexboxes. Is this true? Is there nothing I could do with clever nesting of semantically superfluous elements and certain styles set to `auto`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the right `div` has some set width (either in % or px), then yes, you can let the left `div`'s width be defined by its content while letting the center `div` fill in the remaining space:

```
#right {
  position: absolute; /* position in top right corner */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
}
#center {
  margin-right: 80px; /* same as #right width */
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/JFCHw/)
​

Comment: How would the situation change if I wanted the right div to be adjustable also? Could we perhaps put the left two cols together inside another div, which is then floated?

Comment: Yes, but at this point, you would have to place your elements out of order in terms of DOM hierarchy. The right div would come first, followed by a wrapper div, which would contain the left and center divs. Both left and right would adjust to their content, with the center div taking up the remaining space. See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/JFCHw/1/

Comment: That's pretty fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you'd be better off with simple floated blocks. If you wanted to absolute position all of them together, you could wrap them in an absolute container, and float them inside. Maybe I just don't understand why you need them absolutely positioned, but this seems like a viable option.